# Copying files between jenkins slaves In pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Our goal is to divide our pipeline with multiple agents.

We have a slave called slave1, that has a sole purpose of checkout out on git,
and building executables.

Eventually when slave1 finishes, we'd like to pass it's output to slave2,
which has a sole purpose of testing slave1's executable.

Please notice that the idea here is not to split jobs, but achieving the
files in the same pipeline.

Heres an example of a `Jenkinsfile` that'll make more sense:

```
pipeline
{
    agent
    {
        label 'slave1'
    }
    stages
    {
        stage("Initialize & Build")
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    println("Im starting the pipeline with slave1!")

                    // Builds Files
                    // ....

                    // Has many files that needs to pass to slave2
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Execute & Test")
        {
            agent
            {
                label 'slave2'
            }
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    println("Im in the new slave - slave2!")

                    // How does this slave get the files?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How is it possible to pass these files between the agents?

I read about artifacts, but it seems like it's goal is to return the objects from a job, this isn't necessarily what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your agents are on linux servers, you can simply scp the build output of agent 1 to agent 2.
Also, first you will need to establish passwordless SSH connection between these 2 agents.

Here's an example.

```
pipeline
{
    agent
    {
        label 'slave1'
    }
    stages
    {
        stage("Initialize & Build")
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    println("Im starting the pipeline with slave1!")

                    // Builds Files
                    // ....
 // option 1: copy files in the workspace of agent 2.
                    scp $WORKSPACE/build_output/* <user>@agent2:/home/<user>/workspace/<job_name>/
// option 2: copy files to any known location of agent 2
                     scp $WORKSPACE/build_output/* <user>@agent2:/<destination_path>



                }
            }
        }
        stage("Execute & Test")
        {
            agent
            {
                label 'slave2'
            }
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    println("Im in the new slave - slave2!")

                    //option 1
                         dir($WORKSPACE) {
                               // Test execution steps
                   }
                     // option 2
                          dir(<destination_path>) {
                              // Test execution steps
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea since it isn't scalable.
The whole purpose of this change is to divide between agents to make parts of the pipeline independent =) But thanks for the idea!

Comment: Another option you can try out is have a common location like a mount to which both the agents will have access and dump the build output there. Just a thought!